# Retrieving a value from child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, colorbox

I can't figure out a way to retrieve a value from child window and display it in the colorbox init.

I have a separate page that displays an image, this image is what gets loaded into colorbox.  I need the alt on the image to be the title of the colorbox but am failing at it.

```
cBox = $('.wizard-lightbox').colorbox({
        scrolling:true,
        title:function() {
            var title;
            var save = '<input type="button" id="save-image-submit" value="Save Image" />';

            var accept = '<input type="button" id="accept-button" value="Accept" />';
            var reject = '<input type="button" id="reject-button" value="Reject" />';

            var rotate = '<input type="button" class="rotate-button" id="image_0" value="Rotate Image" />';
            var placeholder = '<div id="placeholder"></div>';
            return '<span id="cboxTitleLeft">' + title + '</span><span id="cboxTitleRight">' +  rotate + accept + reject + "</span>" + placeholder;
        }       
    });
```

In the image page i have tried: `parent.title = $('#desc').val();` with no luck...

Comment: So to be clear you want the `alt` attribute text. Is that correct? And if so you say it is in a child window. What do you mean by that? Is the image on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know what this is suppose to be:**

`parent.title = $('#desc').val();`

**But if you want the `alt` text you should do this:**

`parent.title = $('#desc').attr('alt'); // assuming #desc is the id on your image`

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sLS2P/1/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to answer the previous question, the image is on a separate page being pulled in by colorbox.

Colorbox is not the solution.  I am rewriting to use jquery dialogs instead of colorbox.  It's really hard spinning your wheels on something but dont want to abandon it completely.  In this case, it is the right thing to do.  Halfway through the functionality and it is working so much better.

Thanks for your response!